# max number of scheduled jobs sidekiq

Tags: limit, sidekiq

I imagine it is related to the size of the parameters in a scheduled job and the amount of RAM available to Redis. Even an approximate estimation would suffice.

Assuming:

```
When      Queue                Job           Arguments
tomorrow  idempotent_critical  AddSomeStuff  74, 75, "cos ur rly only after"
```

Would it be reasonable to count the characters on the second line and say 76 chars so one million enqueued similar jobs will occupy ~73MiB? (Thus the limit for a 8GiB of RAM machine is about 100 million of those jobs)

Clarification: What is a rough equation for calculating the max number of jobs sidekiq can schedule?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `redis-cli info` to get Redis memory info before.
2. Create one million scheduled jobs.
3. Use `redis-cli info` to get Redis memory info after.
4. Extrapolate.

Comment: Hey Mike! Appreciate all of your contributions to the community! Could you help me understand why the memory footprint is implementation-specific? It seems like the memory footprint of a job in Redis should be limited to the name of the class and the args to be used. Can't imagine these would vary enough to make a significant difference in memory, but maybe with thousands or millions of jobs?

Comment: It's very dependent on the size of the args, any additional context your app might add, extra features you might use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since Sidekiq uses Redis lists https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists to store jobs the max number would be 4 billion.  I suspect you would hit RAM and other limitations before that.